# I am trying to find an element in an array = 1 and change the element before it, and after it

Tags: arrays, ruby

i understand how to find the 1 in the array, but im not sure how to select the previous value and post value

i know to do this i probably need to take the row and .split it then change the value, but im unsure how to select the previous value in array

```
  def output_image
   @matrix.each do |row|

    puts row.join(" ")

   end
  end

end
image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
image.output_image

the expected result would be row 2 outputs [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: What about row 3?

Comment: You didn't like my question? OK, here's another: what about `Image[2]`?

Comment: Could you work with my example below?

Answer (score 1):

To find an element in an array you can use the index, e.g. for `a = [1,2,3]` you get the first value by using `a[0]`. To get the previous index you can use `a[i - 1]` or `a[i + 1]` where i is the current index.

I suggest to use something like

```
  def output_image
    @matrix.each do |row|
      column_with_one_index = row.index(1)
      next if column_with_one_index.nil?

      row[column_with_one_index - 1] = 'prev'
      row[column_with_one_index + 1] = 'next'
      row.join(" ")
    end
    puts @matrix.inspect
  end
```

The result would be:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  ["prev", 1, "next", 0],
  [0, 0, "prev", 1, "next"],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Or, to return exactly the result you described use:

```
class Image 
  def initialize(array)
    @matrix = array
  end

  def output_image
    @matrix.each_with_index do |row, i|
      column_with_one_index = row.index(1)
      next if column_with_one_index.nil?

      row[column_with_one_index - 1] = 'prev'
      row[column_with_one_index + 1] = 'next'
    end
    @matrix.map do |row| row.join(" ") end
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])

puts image.output_image
```

Then, with the map the result would be

```
0 0 0 0
prev 1 next 0
0 0 prev 1 next
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Edited my answer again, now with a hopefully useful example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i figured it out. I needed to do a loop inside a loop. Loop through the first array then individually loop through each row, store the value of the one then use row, column index -1 == 1 to change the ones i wanted to